# How to expansion a placement new pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, placement-new

Assuming there have a pointer who made by placement new, it's size is 4, how can made it bigger without copy to an other pointer and delete it?

```
int* ptr = (int*)(::operator new(sizeof(int)));   //how to make it bigger than now?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't resize the memory allocated by `::operator new`. The only thing you can do is to delete it using `::operator delete` and then allocate new memory.

PS: Some notes on terminology:

`::operator new` is not placement new. Placement new is invoked using the syntax `new(ptr) class(arguments)` and is used to invoke constructors to initialize memory that has not yet been initialized (such as memory allocated by `::operator new`). `::operator new` is simply called operator new.

The size of a pointer refers to the number of bytes that is used to store the pointer itself (usually 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms and 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms). What you meant is the size of the allocated memory, i.e. the size of the memory that the pointer points to.